# How we can achieve Cross border payment based on xrp-ledger

Tags: node.js, ripple, xrp

I have a query regarding cross border payments
Do XRPL provide cross border payment options, also I have read the XRP-ledger documentation couldn't find any thing regarding cross border payments

Suggestion would be appreciated.*

I have read the XRP-ledger documentation couldn't find any thing regarding cross border payments,
I have read about the xumm on/off ramp but there is no developer development environment(test mode) or sandbox account

Answer (score 0):

The XRP Ledger does not have a concept of borders.

You can transfer value to an account on the XRPL with a [Payment](https://xrpl.org/payment.html) transaction.

There is a company called Ripple using the XRP Ledger. They provide [cross-border payments](https://ripple.com/solutions/cross-border-payments/).